# Pinned Sites in browsers other than IE 9/Win 7

Tags: browser, cross-browser

Is there an equivalent to IE 9's pinned sites feature for other browsers/operating systems?

EDIT:

Pinned sites are basically mini-applications that live on the Windows Task bar. (They remind me of web-based apps in iPhone.) Once "installed" you get jump lists with different activities you can do in the site. It also supports icon overlays so you can post notifications right on the task bar.

I find it to be a really interesting idea, but I wonder if it will catch on if none of the other browsers are willing to support it.

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/internet-explorer/products/ie-9/features/pinned-sites

http://www.beautyoftheweb.com/#/highlights/seamless-with-windows-7

Comment: seems like something for super user, but chrome has the ability to pin tabs

Comment: Could you describe what IE9's "pinned sites feature" does?

Comment: I added it to the original question.

Comment: A pinned tab is nothing like a pinned site. A pinned site is something a website developer has to code, you don't get it for free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see, only IE9 can do that deep kind of site pinning for Windows.  For Mac, there are a few things I've heard of to put a website/webapp in the doc and receive notifications I think.  One tool is called Fluid:
http://fluidapp.com/

But I don't know if that has anything like the Dynamic Jump Lists in Pinned Site buttons.